# ImportError: cannot import name 'pyplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

I'm trying to import pyplot from matplotlib but I get this error:

```
~/PycharmProject/untitled @ jims-mbp (jim) 
| => python math.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "math.py", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/Users/jim/PycharmProject/untitled/matplotlib.py", line 1, in 
<module>
from matplotlib import pyplot
ImportError: cannot import name 'pyplot'
___________________    | ~/PycharmProject/untitled @ jims-mbp (jim) 
| =>
```

I've seen other posts related to this issue but no answers that solve my problem.

this is what I'm running:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
```

Comment: "I've seen other posts related to this issue but no answers that solve my problem" isn't helpful unless you tell us which ones you've tried and what didn't work. Without knowing what you've already tried, all anyone can do is suggest all the most obvious things that should work—which will do you no good, because you've already tried them, and they didn't work. Or maybe you've already tried them, but did something wrong, which we _could_ debug for you, but not if we can't see exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: You forgot to define `pyplot` in `/Users/jim/PycharmProject/untitled/matplotlib.py`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you run into problems, as your file is called `"/Users/jim/PycharmProject/untitled/matplotlib.py"` and you have a naming conflict there.

Try to rename it to sth else and rerun.